# How can I call a component inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, coffeescript

I want to call a **CategoryProduct** component inside a forEach loop in the **CategoryBox** Component.

My **input**:

```
- productos =  [ { header: 'car', src: 'picture.jpg', description: 'the car' } ]
```

CategoryProduct component:

```
@CategoryProduct = React.createClass
render: ->
 div
  className: 'CategoryProduct'
  div
    className: 'header'
    @props.header
  div
    className: 'picture'
    @props.src
  div
    className: 'description'
    @props.description
```

Then I try to call the **CategoryProduct** component in the CategoryBox component:

```
@CategoryBox = React.createClass
 render: ->
  div
   className: 'CategoryBox'
   @props.productos.forEach (prod) ->
     React.createElement CategoryProduct, { header: prod.header, src: prod.src, description: prod.description }
```

But the **output** is nothing. I did a console log inside the loop and is getting in without problem but it doesn't go inside the **CategoryProduct** component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into coffeescript's [loops and comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops). They are much nicer than the JS ones and due coffeescripts implicit return, the loop will return an array containing the values on the last line inside the loop.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = for item in a 
  z = item * 2
  z + 1
```

Then `b` would be `[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]`

So your code would read:

```
@CategoryBox = React.createClass
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'CategoryBox'
      for prod in @props.productos
       React.createElement CategoryProduct, prod
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` doesn't return [anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value). You have to use `Array.prototype.map()` instead.

So your code should look like this

```
@CategoryBox = React.createClass
 render: ->
  div
   className: 'CategoryBox'
   @props.productos.map(prod) ->
     React.createElement CategoryProduct, { header: prod.header, src: prod.src, description: prod.description }
```